# CakePHP Ajax Add form from View (related )

Tags: ajax, cakephp

i´ve got a view of my client (http://localhost/client/view/3) and in related section I have his adress.
Cakephp automatically builds that. When you click on Add Adress button new page comes up (http://localhost/addess/new) and when you save that it goes to http://localhost/addess/index

what I need is to ajax this view and get all working together. I need to go to http://localhost/client/view/3 push Add Adress and get addrees/new form visible (<- easy with jQuery) but how can I save the new adress and get adress div updated??

any example??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php script you make the AJAX call to is where you need to do the save. When you have done that, you can pass out the data for the address div as xml or a javascript object and read it with the AJAX javascript in the original view.

Comment: mmhhh I understand but do you have any example url?